# POSIX Shell Implementation in C

Tags: c, shell, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, lexer

I am currently working on a POSIX shell implementation in C that should work as described by SCL.

For now I have created the following lexer:

```
struct lexer
{
    char cur_char;
    long cur_pos;
    FILE* stream;
};

struct lexer *init_lexer(FILE* stream);

struct token *get_next_token(struct lexer *lexer);
enum token_type get_next_token_type(struct lexer *lexer);

int is_empty(struct lexer *lexer);

void free_lexer(struct lexer *lexer);
```

I am using this lexer to creates AST (I am creating my AST recursively) and I have a parse function for each grammar rule (Only 3 for now: SIMPLE_COMMAND, COMMAND_LIST IF_COMMAND).

I am using this function to decide what type of node should I generate:

```
struct ast_node *parse(struct lexer *lexer)
{
    if (lexer == NULL)
        return NULL;

    enum token_type type = get_next_token_type(lexer);

    struct ast_node *base_node;

    switch (type)
    {
    case WORD:
        base_node = (struct ast_node *)parse_command_list(lexer);
        break;
    case NEWLINE:
        return NULL;
    case IF:
        base_node = (struct ast_node *)parse_if_command(lexer);
        break;
    default:
        base_node = NULL;
        break;
    }

    return base_node;
}
```

I have some problem with that function the first is that:
if I get the first token from the lexer and then I parse the command the first will not be available in the parsing function (I added get_next_token_type that get the type of the next token without advancing in the lexer to fix this for now).

I have been wondering if there would be a better way to decide which grammar rule parse.
Also, I am not sure how I would parse pipeline command because I will have to know that I have a pipe before creating the AST of the tokens at the left of the pipe .
I was wondering if keeping token in a stack or add a get_prev_token function in the lexer could be interesting?

Thank you for your help, have a nice day!

Edit: Also if you would have some documentation it could really help me the only helpful documentation I found for now is this on :https://shell.multun.net/

Comment: By "SCL", do you mean the Posix definition? That includes a complete grammar and some parsing notes. What other documentation do you require?

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you think that "I will have to know that I have a pipe before creating the AST of the tokens at the left of the pipe". The fact that a command is the left-hand side of a pipe should not make the slightest difference to its AST representation. You don't need to know until you start to execute the pipeline, and by then you know all of its components.

Comment: If you want to parse with single lookahead recursive descent - a fine choice and what it appears you're doing - then read up on context free grammars and how to transform a grammar into LL(1) form. [Here is a tiny example](https://gist.github.com/gene-ressler/8278298) that parses arithmetic conditional expressions to DAGs, which are just ASTs with equal chunks merged.  Unfortunately it's in Java, not C, but the ideas are the same. You can use it for examples of how to order operations to construct nodes.